# Using machine learning algorithm to approximate a matrix?

Tags: machine-learning, backpropagation, matlab

I don't know if this is a good question. I would like to use machine learning to approximate a matrix. For example, a very simple one as

\begin{align}
A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 \\
 0& 2 
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

I can easily generate many input-output pairs by left-multiplying the input with $A$. The input are random vectors of dimension $2\times 1$. I use the following neural network to do the job

input layer : 2 nodes;

hidden layer : 1 node;

output layer : 2 nodes.

A very simple Matlab code is written as follows, but it doesn't work. The testing results simply blow up, showing NaN.

```
m=1000;                % number of input-output pairs      
alp=0.001;             % learning rate

inp=rand(2,m);         % random input
oup=[1 0;0 2]*inp;     % constructing output

W1=rand(1,2);          % initialise the weights
W2=rand(2,1);

for epoch=1:1000       % running for 1000 epochs
    for i=1:m          % do the forward propagation and backpropagation
       a1 = inp(:,i);
       z2 = W1*a1;    a2 = actf(z2);
       a3 = actf(W2*a2);

       delta2 = a3 - oup(:,i);
       delta1 = actfd(z2).*(W2'*delta2);   

       W2 = W2 + alp*delta2*a2';
       W1 = W1 + alp*delta1*a1'; 
    end
end
```

actf here is the activation function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ and actfd is its derivative $f(x)=x(1-x)$. I see no problem of overfitting since in $A$ matrix there are 4 entries and the NN also has 4 weights in total. But the code seems to be wrong.

I'm wondering if people here know how to solve this problem (approximating a matrix using ML)? Did I do anything wrong in the code above?

Thanks in advance for your help. Any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: Does it work? what are you asking for help with?

Comment: edited accordingly.